# Row for each date from start date to end date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, recursive-query

What I'm trying to do is take a record that looks like this:

```
 Start_DT    End_DT     ID
4/5/2013    4/9/2013    1
```

and change it to look like this:

```
    DT      ID
4/5/2013    1
4/6/2013    1
4/7/2013    1
4/8/2013    1
4/9/2013    1
```

it can be done in Python but I am not sure if it is possible with SQL Oracle?  I am having difficult time making this work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**connect by level** is useful for these problems. suppose the first CTE named "*table_DT*" is your table name so you can use the select statement after that.

```
with table_DT as (
    select 
        to_date('4/5/2013','mm/dd/yyyy') as Start_DT, 
        to_date('4/9/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as End_DT, 
        1 as ID
    from dual
)
select 
    Start_DT + (level-1) as DT, 
    ID
from table_DT
connect by level <= End_DT - Start_DT +1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive subquery-factoring clause:

```sql
WITH ranges ( start_dt, end_dt, id ) AS (
  SELECT start_dt, end_dt, id
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT start_dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY, end_dt, id
  FROM   ranges
  WHERE  start_dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY <= end_dt
)
SELECT start_dt,
       id
FROM   ranges;
```

Which for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( start_dt, end_dt, id ) AS
SELECT DATE '2013-04-05', DATE '2013-04-09', 1 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> START_DT            | ID
> :------------------ | -:
> 2013-04-05 00:00:00 |  1
> 2013-04-06 00:00:00 |  1
> 2013-04-07 00:00:00 |  1
> 2013-04-08 00:00:00 |  1
> 2013-04-09 00:00:00 |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f1b60b74c44fdaec2fe87127efed6328)*

Comment: The `where` clause of the recursive member could be simplified as `WHERE start_dt < end_dt`

Comment: @GMB No, it cannot if you have dates with a non-midnight time component. If the `start_dt` is `2013-04-08 01:23:45` and the `end_dt` is `2013-04-09 00:00:00` then you would end up with a date that is after the end date if you use `start_dt < end_dt`.

Comment: Indeed - but that's not what OP is showing in their sample data though.

Comment: This answer is not just for the OP, it is for all other users who have the same problem and if one of those people has non-midnight dates then this answer will work as-is. If it only works for a limited amount of cases (i.e. using `start_dt < end_dt` when the `start_dt` and `end_dt` have identical time components) then there will be users who get an answer they do not expect.